# integrate timepicker with cordova local notifications

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have the cordova local notifications plugin installed and working. What I need is to create a timepicker that will allow a user to select a time that they want to set the notification for (ie a reminder). Is there a way to create a timepicker that will allow me to pass values to the cordova local notfications .schedule({})?

I am not providing code as all my code is working, but can't find a way to implement the timepicker.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use existing solutions to embed a timepicker, for example this one https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-timepicker

Comment: I had already done so, but wanted to mark this as the answer as this is what worked for me. Thx